# is it safe for Mac Terminal username followed by @192

Tags: mac, terminal

I notice that each time my macos reboot, my terminal username becomes myusername@192. After a couple of minutes, it turns into myusername@MacBook-Pro.

1. What happens during my macos system reboot and what makes it change back to myusername@MacBook-Pro again.
2. Is @192 a hostname? And is it safe for my mac to have a @192 as a hostname?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal

Answer (score 0):

The default bash shell prompt uses `\h` in the PS1 prompt-string which
causes bash to take your IP address and do an reverse DNS lookup to get
the name.

The Mac OSX reverse DNS lookup code will return whatever the DNS server
say is your system name. If the DNS server does not have a name for your
IP address, then Mac OSX will use your System
*Preferences > Sharing > Computer name*.

So when you move your location, you are getting different DNS servers.
In a home situation, you router tends to be the local DNS server.

You could change your PS1 prompt to explicitly be whatever you want
in `.bash_profile` (or `.profile`).

For setting your computer-name, see the post suggested by user Tetsujin:
[OS X computer name not matching what shows on terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30552/os-x-computer-name-not-matching-what-shows-on-terminal)